# Storing contents from Viewbag into a local jquery array or object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, arrays, list

Let's imagine a situation like this:

I have an ViewBag dynamic object which is basically a list fille with some results;

Scenario 1:

1. User 1 comes in and fills the ViewBag.Products object with a list of 50 items inside;

Scenario 2:

2. User 2 comes in and fills ViewBag.Products object with a list of 50 NEW items which ARE DIFFERENT than the previous 50 ones of a user 1.

Now when the both users get displayed results onto their page, which is located at /Analyze/Index <- view

I enable them so that they can sort out that list by a certain property of a class which is located inside the object like this:

```
public JsonResult GetSortedBySales()
    {
        var list = lista.OrderByDescending(x => x.SaleNumber).ToList();
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    public JsonResult GetSortedByFeedback()
    {
        var list = lista.OrderByDescending(x => x.Feedback).ToList();
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

As you can see this produces an issue like this:

The last user that added it's own items to the list are the items which will be shown to User 1 when he tries to sort out the list, since the list is now filled with User #2's items...

The list is filled with the items from the eBay API, therefore I cannot guarantee the integrity and uniqueness of the data to each user...

What I thought I can do here?? Is that I can store these items from the list somehow into the local jquery array and then perform the sorting from that local array, so that each jquery array is local to each user in their browser and no mixing of data is done...

Do you guys understand me what I'm trying to achieve here?

I apologize if my English is bad, I've tried my best to explain the issue that I have.

Edit: here is more data on what I'm trying to achieve

Basically I have a form where users perform a search of ebay items based on a certain keyword. After the search via http request I display the results to them in a manner where they can select all of those products in a table and then perform analyzing of those selected products.

Then they are transferred with another page with the analyzed data and I display the results to them in the list object called "lista".

The "lista" list is always filled differently based on what the user searches on the page via the process that I just explained above.

So the "lista" object is always filled with the new data and when the user performs sorting of data in list "lista" they are always displayed differently if 2 users perform analyzing of data like in scenario 1 and 2 that I explained above.

Does this helps?

Edit 2:

Here is a graphical explanation of what I ment

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

P.S. the "lista" list is declared as static, is that what's causing the issue?

Edit again:

Okay so guys I've found a way so that the data isn't changed when I sort it. Instead of doing a jQuery post, I perform sorting of data based on two extra attributes that I added into my table tr - sales and feedback and then sorted it like following:

```
$(".feedbackClick").click(function() {
    var $wrapper = $('#tableSellers');

    $wrapper.find('.test').sort(function(a, b) {
        return +$(b).attr('feedback') - +$(a).attr('feedback');
    }).appendTo($wrapper);
});
```

This sorts the data locally in jQuery thus no data is lost at the time when multiple users perform a search.

Comment: Your English is mostly fine. However, could you explain exactly what you're trying to achieve in a little more detail?

Comment: @ic3man7019 ty. Yes...  I will edit my initial question

Comment: @ic3man7019 I edited my initial question with more details, does this helps ? :)

Comment: @ic3man7019 I added the graphical steps to the issue as well

Comment: Why is `lista` declared as `static`?

Comment: @ic3man7019 so that I can use it in multiple functions across the controller... I actually solved the issue by not calling the sorting method from controller like I've shown in above example, but rather perform the sorting in jQuery by declaring 2 extra tags and sort them like that. In the end I also added a feature where I don't allow user to refrsh the page so that the data isn't lost ... :)

Comment: Ah, I see. Well I'm glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> P.S. the "lista" list is declared as static, is that what's causing the issue?

Yes.  That is the problem.

You should almost never be using static variables in a web site, as those variables will end up being shared across all users.

Comment: Okay I understand now - I will remember this. 
When I do a public static List<strings> lista {get;set;} - it is available across the whole class/controller when I need to use it ... 

But what other way is there to have 1 property inside a class available in multiple method across the class/controller ??

Comment: Instance variables, a.k.a. [Fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118(v=vs.80).aspx).